# Make Sure All Forms In My Form Have Input Before Using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a set of input boxes and you can add more and more sets of these forms if you click the add more button. In my form I can submit data and I have got it to show up when you reload the page. However, I am stuck at making sure all of the fields have values before I run my AJAX. I use Jquery for this project

I cannot use a validation plugin because I am running magento and every time I try running the plugins in "No Conflict Mode" the plugins do not seem to work. Because I am running Magento this means I need to run Jquery in no conflict mode.

I have seen other solutions for this however they are all to do with input boxes and I have 1 input boxes and 2 select boxes. How can I make sure that all the input boxes are filled before and that all the select boxes that are not disabled have something selected before the `ajax` call?

Here is part of my HTML:

```
<form>
    <input id="12">
    <select id="1">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">select please</option>
        <option value="01">Option 1</option>
        <option value="02">Option 2</option>           
     </select>
     <select id="2">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Please</option>
        <option value="01">Option 1</option>
        <option value="02">Option 2</option>           
     </select>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById(ID).value!=''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a click event, if you use `.val()` on your `<select/>`, it will return `null` if there is no `value` attribute on your `<option/>`.

Note: This will not work if you put a value attribute on your options.

Edit: Doing a `!==` compare will be faster.

```
$("#submit-button").click(function(){
    //if this is true, then it is valid
    alert($("#1").val() !== null);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by getting the inputs value into a property.

This script would alert the number of how many inputs aren't complete or missing with base in your structure.

*(no jQuery)*

```
var myForm=document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
var formSelectors=myForm.getElementsByTagName("select"),
    formTextBoxes=myForm.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    missing=0;
var i,
    length=formSelectors.length;
for(i=0;length>i;i++){
    if(formSelectors[i].value===formSelectors[i].children[0].value)
        //Check if select value is equal to
        //select please or Select please
        //MISSING! (select)
        missing++
}
length=formTextBoxes.length;
for(i=0;length>i;i++){
    if(formTextBoxes[i].value.length===0)
        //MISSING! (input)
        missing++
}
alert(missing)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if($('#12').val()!='') {
// your code
}
```